# How to set the outer margins in ggplot2?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, cowplot

In R basic plot, the outer margins can be controlled through `oma()`, and I wonder if there is a similar function in `ggplot2` to do this. As the following figure shows, the is almost no space between and figure and the edge of the page. Thanks a lot. [image]

Please note that I am not asking about set margins between each sub-plot (this can be done by `plot.margin=` in ggplot2). What I am asking is how to set the outer margin for the whole figure (something like `oma` in R basic plot). Thanks.

```
require(cowplot)
require(ggplot2)
x=1:50
y=x^2
z=rep(c("p","sp","n","sn","nt"),each=10)
mydata= data.frame(x,y,z)
plot1=ggplot(mydata,aes(x=x,y=y,group=z))+geom_point(aes(shape=z,color=z),size=1)+scale_shape_manual(values=c(19,1,19,17,17))+scale_color_manual(values=c("blue","black","red","blue","red"))
plot2=ggplot(mydata,aes(x=x,y=y,group=z))+geom_point(aes(shape=z,color=z),size=3)+scale_shape_manual(values=c(19,1,19,17,17))+scale_color_manual(values=c("blue","black","red","blue","red"))
plot3=ggplot(mydata,aes(x=x,y=y,group=z))+geom_point(aes(shape=z,color=z),size=5)+scale_shape_manual(values=c(19,1,19,17,17))+scale_color_manual(values=c("blue","black","red","blue","red"))
plot4=ggplot(mydata,aes(x=x,y=y,group=z))+geom_point(aes(shape=z,color=z),size=7)+scale_shape_manual(values=c(19,1,19,17,17))+scale_color_manual(values=c("blue","black","red","blue","red"))
plot_grid(plot1, plot2, plot1,plot1, align='h', labels=c('a', 'b',"c","d"))
```

Comment: Huh. `plot_grid` returns a ggplot object. go figure. Just add `+  theme(plot.margin=margin(30,30,30,30))` (or whatever space you need)

Comment: Thanks a lot. But what I am asking is how to set the outer margin for the whole figure (something like `oma` in R basic plot), not for the sub-plot.

Comment: it's a bit of hack, but `gridExtra::grid.arrange(plot1, plot2, plot1,plot1,left="",top="",bottom="",right="")` will give you some outer margins ...

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to stay with `cowplot`, you could use `ggdraw()` + `draw_plot()`, as demonstrated at the bottom of the [`cowplot` introduction](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cowplot/vignettes/introduction.html).  The idea is to set the width and height of each plot to be smaller than they would otherwise be (in this case, 0.4), and position the plots accordingly (e.g. at `(0.1, 0.1)` rather than (`0, 0`):

```
ggdraw() +
  draw_plot(plot1, .1, .5, .4, .4) +
  draw_plot(plot2, .5, .5, .4, .4) +
  draw_plot(plot3, .1, .1, .4, .4) +
  draw_plot(plot4, .5, .1, .4, .4) +
  draw_plot_label(LETTERS[1:4], 
                  x = c(.1, .5, .1, .5), 
                  y = c(.9, .9, .5, .5), size = 15)
```

[image]